# Why can't I use $app in called function for Slim?

Tags: php, json, slim

I am trying to make a reusable function, but everytime I try to use $app in the remote function, I get a blank screen. Here is what does work:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

//GET CHAPTERS
$app->get(
    '/chapters',
    function () use ($app) {
        $app->contentType('application/json');
        executeSql('SELECT * FROM chapters ORDER BY id');
    }
);

//GENERIC SQL EXECUTE
function executeSql($sql) {
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($results);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

But I am trying to move the json header in the function and can't get this to work (gets the blank white screen):

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

//GET CHAPTERS
$app->get(
    '/chapters',
    function () {
        executeSql('SELECT * FROM chapters ORDER BY id');
    }
);

//GENERIC SQL EXECUTE
function executeSql($sql) use ($app) {
        $app->contentType('application/json');
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($results);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Is something wrong with my syntax or how I'm using PHP? I also tried without the "use ($app)" at all but still same problem.

Comment: Do you get any error since you get a blank page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy way to fix this is to use getInstance();

```
function yourFunction(){
   $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this code it works. But I am a PHP newbie can anybody over here verify is this the right way to do it.

Comment: yes, Slim developer specifically create the getInstance method so that $app can be used in function

Answer (score 5):

You could always pass the $app object as an argument to your function.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

//GET CHAPTERS
$app->get(
    '/chapters',
    function () use ($app) {
        executeSql($app, 'SELECT * FROM chapters ORDER BY id');
    }
);

//GENERIC SQL EXECUTE
function executeSql(\Slim\Slim $app, $sql) {
        $app->contentType('application/json');
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($results);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? Currently am passing $app object as an argument. I don't know is it the right way to do it..

Comment: Why not? Your only other alternative is to access the Slim object with a global declaration. You typically don't want to use global variables. Passing the Slim object as a parameter is a pattern called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). DI is a good practice to follow, as it decouples the code in a function from the dependencies it relies on.

Answer (score 2):

It is cleaner to keep database calls and app logic/presentation separate. I would return your "chapters" object immediately and handle anything else outside of the executeSql function.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// GET CHAPTERS
$app->get('/chapters', function () use ($app) {

  $app->contentType('application/json');

  $chapters = executeSql('SELECT * FROM chapters ORDER BY id');

  if ($chapters) {
    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    echo json_encode($results);
  } else {
    $app->response->setStatus(400);
    echo '{"error":{"text":"error getting chapters"}}';
  }

});

// GENERIC SQL EXECUTE
function executeSql($sql) {
  try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    return $results;
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `use` keyword only applies to closure constructs, apart from the use with namespaces. so what your doing with a regular function is not supported. you will have to use `global $app` which is usually considered bad practice.